# Add Fractions in C as numerator and denominator

Tags: c

How can I add fractions like 1/200 + 1/300 + 1/500 und print the result as `1/96.774194` and not `0,010333`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()

{

   double R1 = 500.0, R2 = 200.0, R3 =  300.0;
   double series, Parallel;
   series = R1 + R2 + R3;
   Parallel = 1/R1 + 1/R2 + 1/R3;

   printf("series: \n");
   printf("%f Ohm + %f Ohm + %f Ohm = ", R1, R2, R3);
   printf("%f Ohm", series);
   printf("\n\nParallel: \n");
   printf("1/%f Ohm + 1/%f Ohm + 1/%f Ohm = ",R1, R2, R3);
   printf("%f Ohm", Parallel);

   return 0;
```

Comment: `printf("1/%f Ohm", 1/Parallel);`?

Comment: it worked, great thanks a lot

Comment: OT: Notice that your prints for parallel are wrong. `1/R1` is **not** Ohm (it's Siemens or mho)

Comment: i meant 1/ R Ohm, 
the ohm is the denominator